# jquery attr selector does not select the whole value of the attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I've a button and that has an attribute called fromname.

```
<input name='booknow' type='button' onClick='bookNow(this);' value='Book Now' id='saloon' fromname='london heathrow airport' toname="london luton airport"/>
```

but when I try to access the attribute fromname that will give me only "london" not "london heathrow airport"

```
function bookNow(obj)
{
    var fromname=$(obj).attr("fromname");
    alert(fromname);
}
```

How can find the whole attribute value?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fJpv8/ Maybe `obj` is not what you think it is. It's also better if you use `data-*` attributes instead of custom ones.

Comment: In your markup, you're using XHTML syntax (the `/>` at the end of your `input`), but `onClick` is not XHTML, it's HTML-only (in XHTML it's `onclick` in all lower case, and case matters). Not that that's the problem, which suggests that your XHTML is being served with MIME type `text/html`, and thus being treated as tag soup.

Comment: What would this have to do with `jquery-selectors`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(obj).attr("fromname");
```

Instead of `prop`.

---

http://jsfiddle.net/CcG6k/

Comment: sorry i typed wrongly i used attr instead of prop I've changed the question just now

Comment: Maybe @ArooranS wants $(obj).attr('name');

Comment: thanks @Xander when i regiser that function to window.booknow then it's working. any difference?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code and it didn't work because the call couldn't resolve the method (`bookNow`) in the current context. Thus, adding it to the global (`window`) scope resolved it. This could be written cleaner using unobtrusive JS...

Answer (score 1):

<s>I'm surprised it's giving you anything at all. It's an *attribute* not a property. You want `attr`, not `prop`.</s>

The question seems to have changed and now you're using `attr`, so the above doesn't apply. All I can saw is "works for me": http://jsbin.com/uvevay (and more to the point, *should* work).

---

Side note: Rather than old-fashioned `onclick` attributes in your markup, if you're using jQuery anyway, I'd hook things up in a modern way:

```
<input name='booknow' type='button' value='Book Now' id='saloon' fromname='london heathrow airport' toname="london luton airport"/>
```

and

```
$("#saloon").click(bookNow);
```

...where `bookNow` becomes:

```
function bookNow()
{

    var fromname=$(this).attr("fromname");
    alert(fromname);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr()`:

```
$('input').attr('fromname')
```